# Custom CSS dropdown box fades before being able to click the dropdown container

Tags: html, css, sass

I am trying to write a custom CSS dropdown component. I have gotten it to show the drop-content when hovering over the dropbtn, however the drop-content disappears too fast to click anything in it.  I've tried adding a transition-timing-function ease-in-out onto the dropdown-content css, but it doesnt work :S

```
<div class="dropdown">
            <button class="dropbtn">
              Filters
              <span class="dropbtn__right-chevron"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right" /></span>
            </button>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
              <div
                class="span"
              >
                <button
                  type="button"
                  class="btn btn-tiled quaternary"
                >
                  Send Message
                </button>
              </div>
              
              <div

                class="span"
              >
                <button
                  type="button"
                  class="btn btn-tiled quaternary"
                >
                  Unarchived
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
```

SCSS

```
.dropbtn {
  @include boxShadow;
  position: relative;
  background-color: $color-accent-light;
  color: $color-white;
  padding: 1.5rem;
  font-size: $default-font-size;
  border: none;
  min-width: 15rem;
  border-radius: 3px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  &__right-chevron {
    margin-left: 1rem;
    display: inline-block;
    transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.7s;
  }
  &:focus {
    outline: none;
  }
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;

  &:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
    visibility: visible;
    animation: fade 0.4s;
  }

  &:hover .dropbtn > .dropbtn__right-chevron {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
  }

  &:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: $color-accent;
  }
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: $color-white;
  min-width: 15rem;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;

  & .btn {
    border-radius: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    border: 0px solid $color-tertiary-dark;

    &:hover {
      color: $color-tertiary-dark;
      border: 0px solid $color-tertiary-dark;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is happening because when you hover, the css is changed to `display: block` for `dropdown-content`. But again when you are trying to click, that means you are not hovering anymore the **button**.

Try putting the `dropdown-content` inside the button.

Example:

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">
              Filters
       <div class="dropdown-content">
          //content here
       </div>
    </button>
</div>
```

and CSS

```
.dropbtn {
  .dropdown-content{
    display: none;
  }
  &:hover{
    .dropdown-content{
       display: block;
    }
  }
}
```